# 3 Columned Ribbon isn't working the way I want it to

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a pretty simply website for a friend. In the design, he wants a ribbon to stretch out horizontally in the middle of the page.

Like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRX0l.jpg

My attempt at doing this was to crop the 'ribbon' parts of the right and left and display those images while floating them to the right and left. Then creating a content div, centering it to fill in the middle of the ribbon. This solution is super sloppy and doesn't work well at all. Here's a picture of it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTURS.jpg

The resolution is kinda off, but you can see that the border of the middle div are off, and when stretching or shrinking the page, the percent width of the middle div messes the whole thing up.

Heres my HTML/CSS

```
<div class='ribbon-container'>
    <div id='ribbon-left'>
    </div>
    <div id='ribbon-right'>
    </div> 
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <div id='ribbon-middle'>
    </br>
        <center>
            <span class='ribbon_header'>Food Around Your School</span>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>

.ribbon-container { width:100%; height:118px; position:relative;}
#ribbon-left { background-image:url('images/ribbon_left.png'); width:117px; height:119px; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}
#ribbon-right { background-image:url('images/ribbon_right.png'); width:117px; height:119px; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;}
#ribbon-middle { width:85%; height:81px; background-color:#b5b5b5; border:7px; border-top-style:solid; border-bottom-style:solid;  border-color:#61615f;top:0; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: I'm thinking you'd be best off using SVG (http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) if you want a variable width ribbon, or use a fixed width ribbon if you're using the method above. Trying to have the three divs resize properly is going to be a challenge.

Comment: I need a percent width for the middle bar. Think of yelp.com header. I have basically no experience with SVG, but thanks for the link, seems like this is what I need and i'm going to try and figure this out.

Comment: Actually, you can accomplish this using absolute positioning. I've posted an example below.

Answer (score 0):

You're just gonna have to size everything in the same units. I'd suggest just using pixels unless you're going with a responsive design, and if you're going with a responsive design, I'd suggest using something like [foundation.js](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Edit: and +1 to Michael Peterson's SVG idea. That's a good one too.

Comment: Well most of the website is already designed, so I can't just switch to foundation

Comment: @user2444539 i think SVG is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try setting

```
.ribbon-middle{
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 120px;
}
```

where ribbon's padding is the width of the left/right images. then you will have the text always visible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the height of the banner is not changing, you can accomplish this using by using a horizontally-repeating image as the background for the banner and then using absolute positioning for the left and right portions of the banner.

The html becomes:

```
<div class='ribbon-container'>
    <div id='ribbon-left'></div>
    <div id='ribbon-right'></div>
</div>
```

And the css becomes:

```
.ribbon-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/LVXiQ37.jpg') top left repeat-x;
}
#ribbon-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 112px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/2MOcrO9.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
#ribbon-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 97px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Q6NmXR6.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
```

I've done a really crude mock-up using the initial image you posted. The problem is that the image itself is not perfectly horizontal, so it looks like the right side does not line up in my fiddle, but if you are more careful in creating the initial image, this will work. And I haven't added text, but this can be done using absolute positioning as well, or another method I'm sure.

You can see the example at: http://jsfiddle.net/M3GmY/